# Помощь в логике

Tags: python

Немного не пойму как сделать. Передается в функцию значение 1 и следом такое же значение.
Как первое отработать, а следующее если она равное предыдущему отбросить.

Comment: использовать yield

Comment: yield тут при чём ещё? Использовать глобальную переменную.

Comment: Немного по подробнее...

Answer (score 2):

Создаём словарь снаружи. Если функция ещё не исполнялась с данным аргументом, заносим ответ в словарь. Возвращаем ответ из словаря. Всё.

```
CACHE = {}

def cached_func(arg):

    if not arg in CACHE:
        CACHE[arg] = .....

    return CACHE[arg]
```

**UPD:**

По просьбе [[@Котик_хочет_кушать](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) убираю сайд-эффект:

```
def cacher(storage):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            k = args + tuple(kwargs.items())

            if not k in storage:
                storage[k] = func(*args, **kwargs)

            return storage[k]
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@cacher({})
def add(a,b, additional=4):
    print("called")
    return a+b+additional
```

В принципе, сторэйдж можно спрятать от греха подальше. Использовал его для тестов.

Comment: Отличный пример увеличения coupling на ровном месте. Почему бы сначала не отфильтровать аргументы, а только потом передавать их в функцию? Или передавать в функцию \*последовательность\* аргументов? Или хотя бы текущий и предыдущий аргумент? Или почему бы не отфильтровать результаты после, сделав zip с исходными аргументами? Любой из этих вариантов же явно лучше, чем `CACHE = { }`.

Comment: Передача аргументов последовательная.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать имеет ввиду почему-бы не проверить какие параметры передаются в функцию до вызова функции, а не в ней самой? А под последовательностью имелось ввиду, ну, если я правильно понял, массив к примеру, или "arg1, arg2, arg3" в строку... А в функции первый в массиве или строке передаваемый параметр считать первым, а остальные последующими с номером n+1.

Comment: @cyberdream

- Это вопрос семантики функции (автор вопроса пожелал не приводить никаких сниппетов, поэтому тут можно только гадать). Если функция ничего не знает про какие-то там повторяющиеся аргументы (это всегда так, если она принимает только \*один\* аргумент), то отбрасывать ненужные значения надо на calling site. Получается решение примерно следующего вида: `foreach x in unique(arguments) : yield function(x)`.

- Если функция на самом деле знает про наличие последовательности аргументов, то этот `unique` можно в том или ином виде перенести прямо в нее.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, я как всегда в шоке от того как ты легко находишь простые ответы на, иногда, сложные казалось-бы вопросы! Я-бы городил тучу проверок из if (x <> argument) { ... } а до подобной конструкции с foreach не догадался не смотря на то что она так очевидна!

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать
Автор вопроса не указал что именно он передаёт в функцию. Поэтому я и расписал простейший общий случай, с учётом возможности, что функция вызывается с неизвестными заранее аргументами. Кстати, замкнуть эту функцию на себя очень просто.