# Замена списка в Python

Tags: python, list

Есть массив адресов старых и новых:

```py
m_old = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2','192.168.0.10','192.168.3.10','192.168.5.10']
m_new = ['1.1.1.1','1.1.1.2','1.1.1.3','1.1.1.4'.'1.1.1.255','1.1.2.1']
```

Необходимо старый список заменить на новый. Решение не очень красивое:

```py
ip = []

def gen_ip():
    for addr in ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'1.1.1.0/24'):
        ip.append(addr)


def test():
    l = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2','192.168.0.10','192.168.3.10','192.168.5.10']
    for k,i in enumerate(l):
        print i,ip[k]

gen_ip()

test()
```

Comment: Молодец, вопрос ты проапдейтил. Только вот фрагмент кода твой делает что-то очень, очень странное. Хорошо, функция `gen_ip` создаёт список айпишников по порядку (0,1,2,3 и т.д.). Но почему бы тогда просто не вывести n первых элементов данного списка?
Сейчас весь твой код укладывается в следующий фрагмент:

    for x, y in enumerate(list(ipaddress.IPv4Network("1.1.1.0/24"))[:5]):
        print(x, y)

Answer (score 2):

```
import ipaddress

ip = []

def gen_ip():
    for addr in ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'10.10.10.0/24'):
       ip.append(addr)

def test():
    l = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2','192.168.0.10','192.168.3.10','192.168.5.10']
    x = 0
    for k in l:
       x+=1
       print k,ip[x]
```

gen_ip()
test()

Comment: Хмм.
    for x, y in enumerate(list(ipaddress.IPv4Network("1.1.1.0/24"))[:5]):
        print(x, y)

Тот же результат.

Comment: С чего же это?

Comment: Кстати, твой код во всех случаях возвращает ip[0].

Если тебе это и нужно, тогда исправляю свой вариант:

for x, y in enumerate(list(ipaddress.IPv4Network("1.1.1.0"))*5):
    print(x, y)

Comment: Исправил свой вариант

Comment: Научись уже задавать вопросы.
Сделал адекватный вариант без глобальных переменных.

Comment: Спасибо! На заметку возьму решение вопрос и второе)

Answer (score 0):

Ты уже совсем мудришь.

```
m_old = m_new
```

и всё.

При этом старый объект (класса list) удалится, и заменится уже существующим.

**UPD**

Либо предложенное тобой решение ничего не делает, либо тебе нужно сделать не то, что ты описал в основном вопросе и в комментарии к этому ответу.

Допустим, что верно первое.

Итак, допустим, у нас будет функция, которая будет принимать старый айпишник и возвращать новый:

```
def change_ip(old_ip):

    # это наша целевая функция. Именно здесь должна быть
    # описана логика, по которой меняется айпишник

    return new_ips[old_ip]
```

Для кэширования ответов, которое ты попросил в комменте, используем кэшировщик, который я описал в своём предыдущем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/272730/python-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=272919#272919):

```
@cacher({})
def change_ip(old_ip):

    # это наша главная функция. Именно здесь должна быть
    # описана логика, по которой меняется айпишник

    return new_ips[old_ip]
```

Допустим, у нас есть список старых айпишников, каждый элемент которого нужно заменить на новый:

```
ips = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2','192.168.0.10','192.168.3.10','192.168.5.10']
```

Теперь, чтобы собственно произвести замену, нам нужно всего-навсего прогнать каждый элемент этого списка через нашу функцию замены. Для этого вполне уместно использовать `map`:

```
ips = map(change_ip, ips)
```

**UPD2**

Правлю ориентируясь на твой код.

```
def gen_ip(mask="10.10.10.0/24"):
    return ipaddress.IPv4Network(mask)

def test():
    old_ips = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2','192.168.0.10','192.168.3.10','192.168.5.10']
    new_ips = gen_ip()
    for k,v in zip(old_ips, new_ips): print(k,v)
```

Comment: Так не пойдет

Comment: 1)Старый список находится в базе
2)Новый список я генерирую из ip по маске 1.1.1.0/19
3)Необходимо чтобы в цикле старый адрес обращался в функцию и возвратил ему новый. Но при условии что в функции где новые адреса их нужно еще хранить в памяти чтобы помнить какой выдал.

Comment: Сделай UPD вопроса. Потому что сейчас твой вопрос выглядит мягко говоря нелепо.

Comment: Пока писал, вопрос решил)